# Magento 2 deployed on Google cloud platform admin password not working

Tags: google-cloud-platform, magento2.1

I have just deployed a Magento 2 site on Google Cloud Platform using their own tool (not bitnami). Everything seems fine but I just cant login with the admin password that was created by the installer. What can be wrong?

I have changed the ip adress to static. Also I wonder how I can point that site to my own domain.

Answer (score 1):

In the end it was done quite easily just by setting up email and domain for google authentication settings in Google Cloud RuntimeConfig API

Comment: hi there i am facing the same issues you faced, can you guide me how you solved your problem.